# COUNTIFS involving Date from Threaded Comment and Variable Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a COUNTIFS horizontally and have 2 issues that I'm wondering if you could help with. For each student, data to count begins in col E and extends to col BB (or the last col with "*"). The result of the =SUM(COUNTIFS()) should go in col C. The function should count major misbehaviors (excluding more minor ones). Notice that cells in col E and beyond each have a comment.

Issue 1 - I'd simply like the COUNTIFS to tally a student's major misbehaviors that have occurred within the past 2 weeks. I'm only interested in seeing the count of this 14-day window. The issue is that this should only involve weekdays, not weekends. Another issue is that we need to use the date/time stamp of the threaded comment. There is only one comment in each of these threaded comments. I'm lost as to how to combine something like ">="&TODAY()-14)) with the comment's date stamp--if this is even possible.

Issue 2 - Rather than building the array string with literal misbehaviors, such as typing "bullying, etc.", I'd like to build it from a list in another sheet, where any behaviors (col B) marked with a "y" for yes (in col A) should be included in the COUNTIFS. That way, if we decide to change the category of a behavior, we won't have to edit every student's row. Cells in the odd gray rows beyond col D in the student tracking sheet use data validation that pull from this other list.

Thanks so much for any help you could provide.

[image: student tracking sheet]
[image]